# dual screen sleep problem

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, sleep

When the computer wakes up (so when I re-log in after he went to sleep) the 2nd screen is a bit messed up. Let's try to explain that better: the content is shifted to the left, meaning that the left part of the window in the right screen is not visible and on the left part of the screen there is a black area.
One image is worth a thousand word, so here comes a screenshot of the problem:
hum, when I take a screenshot the problem is not showing, the 2nd screen looks fine. So here comes a regular foto:
[image]

so there you can see the 2 sides I am missing.
Please ask me if you need more info (and if you give me the command in order to get the info you need you'll save me some google search :)
thanx for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in monitor menu you can fix it . press menu button .

horizontal positon - vertical position

Comment: wow, that was fast and good! thx Enes, it worked. Well, actually, the "Auto Adjust" function is enough. Do you know if I can do something to avoid this problem? I mean, it's great having a solution, but it'd be better to solve the problem.

Comment: OS seperate screen to 2 part and harware send those to each monitor . if we will fix in OS hardware can be overload (because resolutions must change) 
doing in monitor is more better doing in OS . we can do it in OS but you must write positons by pixel

Comment: and i have a questions . it would be everytime after wakeup ?

Comment: ok, so I'm better to press the button when it wakes up, no big deal. And yes, it's every time it wakes up, so far (I've installed the 2nd monitor this morning...). Thanx again for your interest Enes

Comment: you can disable auto adjust in settings